# How to import WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex function from gensim module?

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

When i try to import WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex, it's giving me the following error:

```
>> from gensim.models import WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex
ImportError: cannot import name 'WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex
```

The same issue occurs for `SparseTermSimilarityMatrix` function:

```
>> from gensim.similarities import SparseTermSimilarityMatrix
ImportError: cannot import name 'SparseTermSimilarityMatrix
```

Note: I have installed and imported gensim, gensim.models and gensim.similarities. But still it's giving me the `ImportError` while importing the above mentioned functions.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 6):

Fix is change "models" to "similarities"

```
from gensim.similarities import WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex
```

it works in gensim 4.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Try to check the version of gensim that you are using. Usually, the older versions of gensim cause this issue.

```
from gensim.models import WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex      
print(gensim.__version__)
```

if the gensim version is 3.6.x or older update it to 3.7.x or latest version by running the below command. Once you update gensim version should get rid of this issue.

```
pip install --upgrade gensim
```

Comment: @Srikanth Dasam, if the resolution mentioned above worked. Please mark the answer as accepted.